# Auto Update Dropdrop List and Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I having issues with my dropdown list. As I change the drop down list, final value (button to subscribe) only changes upon boxes are selected. However if example, user chose 1 box every 21 days, but then decides to change to 3 box, the final value don't change until the user selects the number of days again. Is there a way to make it auto update upon the number of boxes selected rather than having an additional step to select the box again to update the value.

Code in HTML:

```
        <span>Select Number of Boxes</span><br>

        <select id="Boxes" class="Boxes" name="Boxes">
          <option value="1box">1 Box</option>
          <option value="3box">3 Boxes</option>
          <option value="6box">6 Boxes</option>
        </select>

        <br><br><span>Select Days</span><br>   

        <div class="container">
          <div class="1box">
            <select class="second-level-select" id="second-level-select-1box">
              <option value="1box14days" selected="selected">14 Days</option>
              <option value="1box21days">21 Days</option>
              <option value="1box30days">30 Days</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="3box">
            <select class="second-level-select" id="second-level-select-3box">
              <option value="3box14days">14 Days</option>
              <option value="3box21days">21 Days</option>
              <option value="3box30days">30 Days</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="6box">
            <select class="second-level-select" id="second-level-select-6box">
              <option value="6box14days">14 Days</option>
              <option value="6box21days">21 Days</option>
              <option value="6box30days">30 Days</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="second-level-container">
          <div class="1box14days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com" method="post" target="_top">
              <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="1 Box Every 14 Days">Receive 1 every 14 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
            </form>

          </div>
          <div class="1box21days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 1 Box Every 21 Days">Receive 1 Box Every 21 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
            </form>

          </div>
          <div class="1box30days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 1 Box Every 30 Days">Receive 1 Box Every 30 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="3box14days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 3 Boxes Every 14 Days">Receive 3 Boxes Every 14 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="3box21days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com" method="post" target="_top">
       <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 3 Boxes Every 21 Days">Receive 3 Boxes Every 21 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="3box30days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 3 Boxes Every 30 Days">Receive 3 Boxes Every 30 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="6box14days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com/" method="post" target="_top">
       <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 6 Boxes Every 14 Days">Receive 6 Boxes Every 14 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="6box21days">
            <br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com/" method="post" target="_top">
       <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 6 Boxes Every 21 Days">Receive 6 Boxes Every 21 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
              </form>
          </div>

          <div class="6box30days"><br>
            <form action="https://www.pp.com/" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Receive 6 Boxes Every 30 Days">Receive 6 Boxes Every 30 Days<br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><span>Subscribe Now</span></button>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Boxes').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
      elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
    else {
      $('.Boxes').val($(".Boxes option:first").val());
      elements.filter('.' + value).show();
    }
  }).trigger('change');

  $("#Boxes").val($("#Boxes option:first").val());
  $('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
    var elements2 = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value2 = $(this).val();

    if (value2.length) { // if somethings' selected
      elements2.filter('.' + value2).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
  }).trigger('change');
  $('div.second-level-container').children('.1box14days').show(); // to hide on mobile
  $('div.second-level-container').children('.3box14days').hide(); // to hide on mobile
  $('div.second-level-container').children('.6box14days').hide(); // to hide on mobile
});
```

Open in JSFiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/jgsg/or73b5f6/3/

Please advise or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the code from the beginning, no matter why. You can go ahead based on this logic. I've changed the name of some classes and value that you can change too. But it's better to use just `number` in `value`.

```js
// detect on load

var selectedBoxs = $('#Boxes option:selected').val();
var selectedDays = $('#Days option:selected').val();

$('#result').text('Receive '+selectedBoxs+' Boxes Every '+selectedDays+' Days');

$('.buttons').html('<button>Subscribe Now For '+selectedBoxs+' Boxes Every '+selectedDays+' Days</button>');

// detect on change

$('#Boxes').change(function(){
var selectedBoxs2 = $('#Boxes option:selected').val();
var selectedDays2 = $('#Days option:selected').val();
$('#result').text('Receive '+selectedBoxs2+' Boxes Every '+selectedDays2+' Days');

$('.buttons').html('<button>Subscribe Now For '+selectedBoxs2+' Boxes Every '+selectedDays2+' Days</button>');
});

$('#Days').change(function(){
var selectedBoxs2 = $('#Boxes option:selected').val();
var selectedDays2 = $('#Days option:selected').val();
$('#result').text('Receive '+selectedBoxs2+' Boxes Every '+selectedDays2+' Days');

$('.buttons').html('<button>Subscribe Now For '+selectedBoxs2+' Boxes Every '+selectedDays2+' Days</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Select Number of Boxes</label>
<select id="Boxes" class="Boxes" name="Boxes">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1 Box</option>
  <option value="3">3 Boxes</option>
  <option value="6">6 Boxes</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Select Days</label>
<select id="Days" class="Days" name="Days">
  <option value="14" selected="selected">14 Days</option>
  <option value="21">21 Days</option>
  <option value="30">30 Days</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<a id="result">Receive 0 Boxes Every 0 Days</a>

<div class="buttons">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, however, where should i place your code in mine? Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I can't really change it like that as the result comes with a link and a button, the button links it to somewhere else and every button are different.

Comment: Thanks for helping my friend. Looking forward to it

Comment: Your code has completely confused me, beside of this, you trying to show `container` based on selected value? tell me what are you trying to do, i write it on my code, i can't work on your code.

Comment: The container is the the results. The result will show X number of box and X days, followed by a button to go to a link. All the links from the button are different

Comment: you can do it in your own format so long as it shows a button with a link. each option is a different button

Comment: What about create dynamic button? see updated answer, is it that you looking after?

Comment: Yes we are almost there. The button should go to a different link based on selection. eg 1 box 14 days go to link 1, 1 box 21 days goes to link 2, and so on until 3 box 30 days goes to link 9

Comment: @JackyGoh now i think you can do it yourself, it so easy, look: `if(selectedBoxs2 == 3 && selectedDays2 == 21){ // do something }` or etc.. you can generate a dynamic link.

Comment: Thanks for your help